# Confused about Server-Sent Events

Tags: php, javascript, web, server-sent-events

I have a page `sse.php` that read data and send it back to client.

It works well except it starting over every N seconds.

I understand that EventSource reconnecting every N seconds 
and my php script is started over again and again.

How do i determine what connection is the first one and what are just a maintaining reconnection?

Then i would know on what connection to run the reading script and on what not.

On WebSockets i know it is connecting only once then i only send data.

How to acquire the same with SSE?

Answer (score 2):

an EventSource connects only ones, it reconnects only, when the connection was closed

you can use "Last-Event-ID" to know what data was delivered to the ES.

for example:

```
data: test
id: 123
```

<-- connection was dropped at this point, `Last-Event-ID: 123` http header will be in the reconnection request